# Internal Server Error in returning arraylist from ajax call

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, angularjs

I have a spring project and i am calling my controller from ajax call and i want to return arraylist of an object. In debug it shows proper contents in java code.But in js it gives error. Internal server error 500 .

Here is my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/viewValidationFailures", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody ArrayList<ErrorTable> viewValidationFailures(
            HttpSession session, Principal principal) {
//      System.out.println("parameter"+parameter);
        ArrayList<ErrorTable> errorTables = null;
        SystemUser systemUser = logincontrollerserviceint.getUserByUsername(principal.getName());


        errorTables = validationErrorControllerInterface.getValidationErrorsByUser(systemUser);

        return errorTables;

    }
```

This is my angular js ajax call

```
var helloApp = angular.module("helloApp", []);
helloApp.controller("HttpController", [ '$scope', '$http',
    function($scope, $http) {
    debugger;
        $http({
            method : 'GET',

            url : 'http://localhost:8080/sms/client/viewValidationFailures',
        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            debugger;
            $scope.errors = data;
             $scope.curPage = 0;
             $scope.pageSize = 10;

             $scope.numberOfPages = function() {
                    return Math.ceil($scope.errors.length / $scope.pageSize);
                };

                $('#LoadingImageDiv').hide();
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            debugger;
            $('#LoadingImageDiv').hide();
        });



} ])
```

This is my ErrorTable class

```
@Column(name = "\"eSTId\"")
    private String eSTId;


    @Column(name = "\"errorCode\"")
    private String errorCode;

    @Column(name = "\"errorDescription\"")
    private String errorDescription;

    @Column(name = "\"timeDate\"")
    private String time;
```

Everytime during ajax call it goes into the error function.

Can somebody suggest me what's wrong here.
I have checked all similar links like 
[Ajax call results in 500 Internal Server Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24241010/ajax-call-results-in-500-internal-server-error)
[Ajax call Gives internal server error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29130901/ajax-call-gives-internal-server-error)
but nothing worked for me.

Comment: A 500 response indicates a problem on the server. Have you checked the server logs?

Comment: Yes there are no errors in the server logs

Comment: please write a try-catch block in your method and print stack trace of exceptions if any happens.

Comment: I am debugging the code it does not give any error in java

Comment: Put http://localhost:8080/sms/client/viewValidationFailures directly into the browser, see the result. What do you get?

Comment: @NickJ tried that.. i am getting same error internal server error

Comment: @kirti i don't know more about java but i notice that there is parameter in you controller like " HttpSession session, Principal principal " and your ajax call don't pass any parameter, so can you check that your controller get parameter in it...

Comment: @VinitPatel No i dont have parameter in the ajax call session and pricipal are used for other reasons

Comment: @kirti I don't for a minute believe you just get 3 words 'Internal Server Error'. There must be more than that. Please copy/paste it into your question.

Comment: @kirti but can you sure that session and pricipal values are get in controller becasue your condition are based on that parameter and more over try with dummy data first return direct string and check whether it's return from ajax call or still you get error,,,

Comment: @NickJ  i agree with you ....there must be some specific error,,,

Comment: @kirti look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25213904/sending-data-from-controller-to-javascript-using-linq-500-internal-server-error  see there is mentation In this case, url parameter is not set to right value.

Comment: Those are not url parameters. If i need to pass url parameters i will have to use @request param. And i am not getting problem in calling url.. I am getting problem in returning arraylist to that url. Plz see spring rest webservice tutorials to check how to pass parameter values.

Comment: You are asking US to see tutorials when you are the one with the problem??????

Comment: Problem is not there thats why i asked to clear the doubts